# Finding a representation $N = x^2 + ny^2$ efficiently

Tags: quadratic-forms, pell-type-equations

I want to find a representation of an integer $N$ of the form $N = x^2 + ny^2$. Any single non-trivial representation (i.e. $x \gt 0, y \gt 0, n \ge 1$) suffices.

A naive algorithm that I have implemented checks for $x, n$ in the ranges

$$
\begin{align}
1 & \le x \le \sqrt N \\
1 & \le n \le \sqrt N
\end{align}
$$

and checks if $Y = N - x^2$ is divisible by $n$ and if it is then checks if $Y/n = y^2$ is a perfect square. If yes, then we have a representation $N = x^2 + ny^2$. This gives a complexity of $O(N)$.

Is there a better algorithm?

*Note:* I know if factors of $N$ are known and both have representations of the form $a^2 + nb^2$, we could use the Brahmagupta identity. In this case factors of $N$ are unknown and I would like to avoid factoring.

Comment: You write that you want to avoid factorisation, yet what you are already doing is in effect factorisation of $N-x^2$ by trial division by $n$. You could do that factorisation a bit smarter, and once you have that prime factorisation find all the solutions for that value of $x$ a bit quicker on average. BTW, it is unclear if you are looking for one specific solution or are trying to find all of them. You could always find a quick solution by putting $y=1$, $n=N-x^2$ for any $x\le\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: If we allow $y=1$ , the solution is trivial. If not , for example $N=110$ does not allow such a representation.

Comment: Ok. I found Cornacchia's algorithm which seems to be related. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornacchia%27s_algorithm 

However, this requires computing square roots modulo $N$ which is almost as hard as factoring $N$.

Comment: Perhaps a modification of Matsunaga’s method would be possible?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434787/matsunagas-method-for-solving-x2y2-p